How can I revert my Jupyter Notebook to an Old Version of Python so that the itemfreq function of scipy.stats will work?
I am trying to implement the codes found in Enes Bilgin's Mastering Reinforcement Learning with Python textbook published in December 2020. Unfortunately, in the world of modern programming, this text is practically ancient, so many of the libraries have been done away with. In particular,
from scipy.stats import itemfreq
s = 4
n = 10 ** 6
visited = [s]

does not work because it is no longer there.
I have tried to implement a virtual environment with Anaconda, which works but the Jupyter notebook does not reflect this.
enter image description here
enter image description here

The [sourc]e link for the function documentation shows it just uses np.unique and np.bincount.
You could make your own copy of that code  http://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L1466-L1504

See the top two answers here for options to how you can connect the kernel to the proper environment to control the version of Python that Jupyter would then use when you activate that environment. However, you may just be better off updating the approaches used. In this example from scipy.stats import itemfreq is not as it was but I suspect it can be easily still be adapted in modern Python and Jupyter. See here. Keeping current with open source programming often requires adapting code. So in ...

 in the long run, developing that skill will serve you better than trying to get an old Python and Python packages to work in an environment.
